# Problem with interfacing ds18b20 and mcp3208 simultaneously

Tags: raspbian, linux

In my project i am trying to interface both DS18b20 and MCP3208. When i interface both any one interface only working but not both(spi and 1-wire) not working simultaneously. 
For ds18b20 i am using using script in this link http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-ds18b20-temperature-sensor-tutorial/
For MCP3208 i am using this script. https://pypi.org/project/mcp3208/

Comment: how are you trying to make them work simultaneously? are you running each script separately in two different "terminals"?

Comment: not running simultaneously at same time. Running in same machine.

Comment: "not working simultaneously" ... how do you know if "not running simultaneously" ... are you saying, if both devices are connected, only one works? which one? is it random? is it the one you run the script for?

Comment: At first enabled spi interface and get values from mcp3208. After that enabled 1-wire and interfaced ds18b20 and got values. Now mcp3208 not giving values showing 0 value.

Comment: right, so what you're saying is, when both are "enabled" (how?) only 1-wire works, SPI does not ... when both "enabled", 1-wire always works, SPI never works ... is that the actual description of the problem?

Comment: Means spi not work when we enable 1-wire. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: yes, it means that ... but that's not what you said in the question

Comment: the solution is ... don't know ... it should work, unless you've done something wrong - how have you "enabled" 1 wire and spi?

Comment: There is no conflict between SPI and 1-wire unless you have introduced one.  We need to see a clear photo(s) of your wiring and listings of the software you are using (not a link to software you may or may not actually be using).

Comment: In addition to the above: also post your /boot/config.txt